# access to dictionaries of lists python

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I have the following structure which I am getting from a response of an API, resulting a pandas.core.series.Series, which is really a list of dictionaries, and then other dictionaries nested.

[image]

By using this chunk of code I can get the values for each key (which are lists, as shown in the image)

```
for key, value in data.items():
    print(value)
```

How could I get the ids (e.g 391, 392, 393) for each of the list elements which has the user set as None, appended to a separate list?

It would be accessing the dictionary, inside the dictionary, and at the same time inside each list with user set as None.

Comment: That is unclear what `data` is, regarding to the code it seems to be a dictionnary, but the image isn't clear. What does `print(data)` gives ?

Comment: you could use a recursive function to print those and check via `isinstance(dict)` for values of the key

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question is a little vague. Try to improve your question. By the way If your data is something like :

```
data = [
    {'user':{'id':1001,'username':'XXX'},'apt':{'id':1,'name':'AAA'}},
    {'user':None,'apt':{'id':2,'name':'BBB'}},
    {'user':{'id':1003,'username':'YYY'},'apt':{'id':3,'name':'CCC'}},
    {'user':None,'apt':{'id':4,'name':'DDD'}}
    ]
```

you can print your items like this :

```
for item in data:
    print('for user','"'+str(item['user'])+'"','apt id is',item['apt']['id'])
```

Results will be like :

```
for user "{'id': 1001, 'username': 'XXX'}" apt id is 1
for user "None" apt id is 2
for user "{'id': 1003, 'username': 'YYY'}" apt id is 3
for user "None" apt id is 4
```